# How to make this button is CSS with Angled , Drop shadow, Inset shadow with flexibility in width

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-webkit

How to make this button is CSS with Angled , Drop shadow, Inset shadow with flexibility in width?

[image]

I've tried to make it here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/6RsnN/ but don't how to give angle to it and how to create cut-out border around it.

And button should be flexible in width.

I'm only making this for iphone so full CSS3 is allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The [final result](http://dabblet.com/gist/2777220) is:

[pure css blue button http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/8258/664d7b5656434db68cbee8b.png](http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/8258/664d7b5656434db68cbee8b.png)

### Demonstration of [flexibility](http://dabblet.com/gist/2782854):

[image]
Although I tried to make a button like in the picture, but some parts may not be the same. Would consider it a *proof of concept*.

This button can be pure `CSS` <strike>only with a lot of extra markup</strike> with this markup:

```
<a class="btn">
    <span class="triangle"></span>
    <span class="btn_inner">
        <span class="triangle"></span>
        Back
    </span>
</a>
```

The main trick for creating triangles with box-shadow includes several steps:

- **Step 1**. Create element '.triangle' - it will be a wrap for real triangle.
- **Step 2**. Apply `position: absolute;`, fix its `width` and `height`:
  red background-color is onle for demo
  [image: step 4]
- **Step 3**. Create big square element '.triangle::before' — it will be 'real' triangle after **step 6**
- **Step 4**. Turn it 45 degrees (`transform: rotate(45deg)`).
- **Step 5**. Add box-shadow.
  The result after step 3 is:
  [image: step3]
- **Step 6**. Add `overflow: hidden;` ***Ta-dum!***
  [image: step 5]

On `.tag_inner` use the same trick, but `box-shadow` should be not `inset` but normal.

Notice, that if you will use this trick always check what `vendor` prefixes must be used and place property without prefix on the last place.

**Update:** Make markup more semantic — only one element for triangle trick.

Comment: @Diodeus, thank you. One minute ago i've improved markup to use less non-semantic element.

Comment: @matmuchrapna - Thanks very much. I would like if you can make the button flexible. So if I change the font-size to lower size then button should be smaller

Comment: @JitendraVyas It is flexible by default. [This fork](http://dabblet.com/gist/2782854) demonstrate flexibility. i will add it to answer.

Comment: @JitendraVyas or it should be smaller in height too?

Comment: @VladimirStarkov - yes smaller in height and width both. If i increase font-size button should be increased in width and height

Comment: @JitendraVyas try to use `em` for sizes instead of `px` in my example

Answer (score 0):

Here's your angle, but since it is already a border, you can't put a border on it:

```
body {padding:40px; background-color: #1693da;}
.input {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 60px;    
    background:#117ebb;
    font-size:60px;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px #003355;
    position:relative;
}

.input:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-32px;
    content:" ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 45px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
    border-right:45px solid #117ebb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for angles but these are fixed width

Comment: No, they are fixed-height. Anyways - I don't think what you're doing is possible without images. Maybe this will help: http://chrisbewick.com/blog/css/generating-double-borders-with-css/

Comment: @Diodeus i posted my pure css solution